# Scaffold-eth's graph_node docker container dies after a few seconds, complaining about invalid collation setting

Tags: docker

I have installed and run scaffold-eth on linux but The Graph node's docker container dies after a few seconds with this output:

```
graph-node_1 | Mar 09 17:30:46.164 CRIT Database does not use C locale. Please check the graph-node documentation for how to set up the database locale, error: database collation is `en_US.utf8` but must be `C`, pool: main, shard: primary, component: ConnectionPool
graph-node_1 | thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'Database does not use C locale. Please check the graph-node documentation for how to set up the database locale: database collation is `en_US.utf8` but must be `C`', store/postgres/src/connection_pool.rs:976:13
graph-node_1 | note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
graph-node_1 | thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: JoinError::Panic(...)', /graph-node/store/postgres/src/connection_pool.rs:484:10
graph-node_graph-node_1 exited with code 101
```

I believe that this page describes the problem and a possible solution:

https://github.com/graphprotocol/graph-node/blob/master/NEWS.md

But, I have not been able to resolve the issue by adding this line to the postgres docker-compose.yml:

POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: -E UTF8 --locale=C

I got the idea that this should have worked from this page:

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

I have no idea what to try next. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
 environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: graph-node
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: let-me-in
      POSTGRES_DB: graph-node
      PGDATA: "/data/postgres"
      POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: "-E UTF8 --locale=C"
```

mine works with this config,
after adding PGDATA: "/data/postgres", it works